# How to integrate banner ads in tvOS?

Tags: swift, tvos, ads, banner-ads

In my application I'm using ads for tvOS. I have tried using the AppLovin SDK for ad implementation but it shows a full screen ad.

I want to show a banner view like scrolling data update in my tvOS app. Can I achieve this with iAd or AdMob on tvOS?

I'm using

```
ALSdk.shared()!.adService.loadNextAd(ALAdSize.sizeInterstitial(), andNotify: self)
```

to load ads.

Then, once an ad is available I'm showing the ad using:

```
ALInterstitialAd.shared().adDisplayDelegate = self
ALInterstitialAd.shared().adVideoPlaybackDelegate = self

if let ad = self.ad
{            
    ALInterstitialAd.shared().showOver(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!, andRender: ad)
}
```

Comment: You should provide code to help other help you

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Storm said, banner ads don't really make sense on a tv. But if you insist, you can create your own banners [natively](https://applovin.com/integration#iosNative%22natively%22).

For example, in your view controller:

```
@interface ALDemoNativeAdProgrammaticViewController ()<ALNativeAdLoadDelegate, ALNativeAdPrecacheDelegate, ALPostbackDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) ALNativeAd *nativeAd;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[ALSdk shared].nativeAdService loadNativeAdGroupOfCount: 1 andNotify: self];
}

#pragma mark - Native Ad Load Delegate

- (void)nativeAdService:(nonnull ALNativeAdService *)service didLoadAds:(nonnull NSArray *)ads
{
    // At this point, the native ad is loaded, but assets not retrieved yet.
    self.nativeAd = [ads firstObject];

    // You can use AppLovin's pre-caching to retrieve assets (app icon, ad image, ad video) locally. OR you can do it with your preferred caching framework.
    // iconURL, imageURL, videoURL needs to be retrieved manually before you can render them. For our example, we'll use AppLovin's caching framework.
    [[ALSdk shared].nativeAdService precacheResourcesForNativeAd: self.nativeAd andNotify: self];
}

- (void)nativeAdService:(nonnull ALNativeAdService *)service didFailToLoadAdsWithError:(NSInteger)code
{
  // Handle error
}

#pragma mark - Native Ad Precache Delegate

- (void)nativeAdService:(nonnull ALNativeAdService *)service didPrecacheImagesForAd:(nonnull ALNativeAd *)ad { }

- (void)nativeAdService:(nonnull ALNativeAdService *)service didPrecacheVideoForAd:(nonnull ALNativeAd *)ad
{
    // This delegate method will get called whether an ad actually has a video to precache or not
    //
    // FINALLY, perform whatever view logic you want with the assets provided in your ALNativeAd property, and show the ad.
}

- (void)nativeAdService:(nonnull ALNativeAdService *)service didFailToPrecacheImagesForAd:(nonnull ALNativeAd *)ad withError:(NSInteger)errorCode 
{
  // Handle error
}

- (void)nativeAdService:(nonnull ALNativeAdService *)service didFailToPrecacheVideoForAd:(nonnull ALNativeAd *)ad withError:(NSInteger)errorCode 
{
  // Handle error
}
```

Note that AppLovin's callbacks are not guanranteed to be invoked on the main queue.

It is also your responsibility to track your own impressions

```
[[ALSdk shared].postbackService dispatchPostbackAsync: ad.impressionTrackingURL andNotify: self];
```

and launch the App store when clicked

```
 [self.nativeAd launchClickTarget];
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasTang , I'll remove the Review comment.

Answer (score 0):

iAd does not support tvOS and [is being discontinued](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a), AdMob does not support tvOS also, and AppLovin only supports full screen interstitial ads on tvOS. So, as of now banner ads are not possible on tvOS. I wouldn't anticipate them becoming available anytime soon either seeing as banner ads wouldn't make much sense on a TV.

Comment: AppLovin discontinued tvOS support in 2017.